# Eclipse Equinox ClassCastException when starting

Tags: java, eclipse

I've googled around for about 2 hours now, and can't find a single other person with this issue. It seems to happen whenever I start Eclipse, and it makes the IDE completely unusable. I've tried switching workspaces and it didn't change a thing.

I'm using Eclipse for Java EE version 4.4.1.

Java Version:

```
java version "1.7.0_72"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_72-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.72-b04, mixed mode)
```

Uname:

```
Linux USERNAME 3.13.0-43-generic #72-Ubuntu SMP Mon Dec 8 19:35:06 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Error log (WORKSPACE/.metadata/.log):

```
!SESSION 2014-12-20 14:51:07.942 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=4.4.1.M20140925-0400
java.version=1.7.0_72
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86_64, WS=gtk, NL=en_CA
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
Command-line arguments:  -data /home/mrlolethan/workspaces/Git Repos -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product

!ENTRY org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration 2 0 2014-12-20 14:51:12.984
!MESSAGE Exception while setting up logging:org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxConfiguration$1 cannot be cast to java.lang.String
!STACK 0
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxConfiguration$1 cannot be cast to java.lang.String
    at org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration.LogHelper.logJavaProperties(LogHelper.java:26)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration.LogPlugin.loadConfiguration(LogPlugin.java:189)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration.LogPlugin.configureLogback(LogPlugin.java:144)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration.LogPlugin.access$2(LogPlugin.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration.LogPlugin$1.run(LogPlugin.java:62)
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)

!ENTRY de.fu_berlin.inf.dpp 2 0 2014-12-20 14:51:18.981
!MESSAGE unexpected method call (NullSarosSession.java:64)

!ENTRY de.fu_berlin.inf.dpp 2 0 2014-12-20 14:51:18.983
!MESSAGE unexpected method call (NullSarosSession.java:64)
!SESSION 2014-12-20 14:53:00.079 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=4.4.1.M20140925-0400
java.version=1.7.0_72
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86_64, WS=gtk, NL=en_CA
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
Command-line arguments:  -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.resources 2 10035 2014-12-20 14:53:04.958
!MESSAGE The workspace exited with unsaved changes in the previous session; refreshing workspace to recover changes.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration 2 0 2014-12-20 14:53:05.702
!MESSAGE Exception while setting up logging:org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxConfiguration$1 cannot be cast to java.lang.String
!STACK 0
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxConfiguration$1 cannot be cast to java.lang.String
    at org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration.LogHelper.logJavaProperties(LogHelper.java:26)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration.LogPlugin.loadConfiguration(LogPlugin.java:189)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration.LogPlugin.configureLogback(LogPlugin.java:144)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration.LogPlugin.access$2(LogPlugin.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration.LogPlugin$1.run(LogPlugin.java:62)
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)

!ENTRY de.fu_berlin.inf.dpp 2 0 2014-12-20 14:53:11.484
!MESSAGE unexpected method call (NullSarosSession.java:64)

!ENTRY de.fu_berlin.inf.dpp 2 0 2014-12-20 14:53:11.487
!MESSAGE unexpected method call (NullSarosSession.java:64)
!SESSION 2014-12-20 14:56:32.205 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=4.4.1.M20140925-0400
java.version=1.7.0_72
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86_64, WS=gtk, NL=en_CA
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
Command-line arguments:  -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.resources 2 10035 2014-12-20 14:56:37.097
!MESSAGE The workspace exited with unsaved changes in the previous session; refreshing workspace to recover changes.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration 2 0 2014-12-20 14:56:37.866
!MESSAGE Exception while setting up logging:org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxConfiguration$1 cannot be cast to java.lang.String
!STACK 0
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxConfiguration$1 cannot be cast to java.lang.String
    at org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration.LogHelper.logJavaProperties(LogHelper.java:26)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration.LogPlugin.loadConfiguration(LogPlugin.java:189)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration.LogPlugin.configureLogback(LogPlugin.java:144)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration.LogPlugin.access$2(LogPlugin.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration.LogPlugin$1.run(LogPlugin.java:62)
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)

!ENTRY de.fu_berlin.inf.dpp 2 0 2014-12-20 14:56:43.558
!MESSAGE unexpected method call (NullSarosSession.java:64)

!ENTRY de.fu_berlin.inf.dpp 2 0 2014-12-20 14:56:43.562
!MESSAGE unexpected method call (NullSarosSession.java:64)
!SESSION 2014-12-20 14:58:25.500 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=4.4.1.M20140925-0400
java.version=1.7.0_72
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86_64, WS=gtk, NL=en_CA
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
Command-line arguments:  -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product -clean

!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.p2.publisher.eclipse 4 0 2014-12-20 14:58:51.835
!MESSAGE Unable to acquire PluginConverter service during generation for: /opt/eclipse/plugins/phxstudios.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.p2.publisher.eclipse 4 0 2014-12-20 14:58:52.445
!MESSAGE Unable to acquire PluginConverter service during generation for: /opt/eclipse/plugins/phxstudios.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.p2.publisher.eclipse 4 0 2014-12-20 14:58:52.671
!MESSAGE Unable to acquire PluginConverter service during generation for: /opt/eclipse/plugins/phxstudios.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.p2.publisher.eclipse 4 0 2014-12-20 14:58:52.822
!MESSAGE Unable to acquire PluginConverter service during generation for: /opt/eclipse/plugins/phxstudios.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.resources 2 10035 2014-12-20 14:58:54.738
!MESSAGE The workspace exited with unsaved changes in the previous session; refreshing workspace to recover changes.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration 2 0 2014-12-20 14:58:55.198
!MESSAGE Exception while setting up logging:org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxConfiguration$1 cannot be cast to java.lang.String
!STACK 0
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxConfiguration$1 cannot be cast to java.lang.String
    at org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration.LogHelper.logJavaProperties(LogHelper.java:26)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration.LogPlugin.loadConfiguration(LogPlugin.java:189)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration.LogPlugin.configureLogback(LogPlugin.java:144)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration.LogPlugin.access$2(LogPlugin.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration.LogPlugin$1.run(LogPlugin.java:62)
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)

!ENTRY de.fu_berlin.inf.dpp 2 0 2014-12-20 14:59:00.771
!MESSAGE unexpected method call (NullSarosSession.java:64)

!ENTRY de.fu_berlin.inf.dpp 2 0 2014-12-20 14:59:00.775
!MESSAGE unexpected method call (NullSarosSession.java:64)
```

Comment: It seems a [bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=445122)

Answer (score 1):

Known Eclipse bug, to be fixed in Eclipse Luna SR2 (4.4.2), which according to https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/development/plans/freeze_plan_4_4_2.php will be released end of Feb (in 1 month from today).

Note the workaround from https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=445122, also given in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26279570/getting-rid-of-org-eclipse-osgi-internal-framework-equinoxconfiguration1-that-c - add this to the INI, worked for me:

```
-Dosgi.configuration.area.default=null
-Dosgi.user.area.default=null
-Dosgi.user.area=@user.home
-Dosgi.instance.area.default=null
```